# Justification, hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, justification

I am a PhD student writing his thesis on overleaf. My supervisor told me to remove hyphenation as it can be distracting however now some words go over the margin (See pic). Could anyone help me modify the justification settings for overleaf or maybe a different way to fix the problem?
My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{4cm}{2cm}{2cm}{0cm}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize, it},format=plain,labelfont={color=blue,bf},justification=justified, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt} % less gaps in itemize sections
\setenumerate{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{20pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\parskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.5\textfloatsep}
\newcommand*{\nchapter}[1]{
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
%       \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {%
            \parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont
           \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
               \huge\bfseries\space\thechapter.\space
%               \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
%           \fi
%           \interlinepenalty\@M
            \Huge\bfseries
            #1\par
            \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
        }
    }
\makeatother
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{10pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

[image: How one of the words go outside the margin]

Comment: you could tell your supervisor that they are wrong and hyphenation is less distracting than over stretched white space, otherwise use `\raggedright` to give up on justification or `\sloppy`to allow space to stretch more.

Comment: why have you commented out `%           \fi
%           \interlinepenalty\@M` ? The missing `\fi`will cause errors and the missing interlinepenalty means you allow a page break in the middle of the title.

Comment: Off-topic: `noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt` may be expressed more succinctly as `nosep`.

Comment: Ask your supervisor to point out authoritative publications claiming that hyphenation is distracting and books where hyphenation is not used. Of course after submitting your thesis.

Comment: The habituation to the huge spaces between words in word processor have done great damage `:)`. There are several tricks that you can use to minimize the number of hyphens of some text in LaTeX without leaving horrible white spaces, but sometimes the only reasonable solution is allow some hyphens, reword the paragraph or use a ragged margin.